# Find every differentiable function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the properties $(f(x))^2f'(x)\geq x^2$ and $|f(x)|\leq x(1+e^{-x})$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I need to find every differentiable function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the properties $(f(x))^2f'(x)\geq x^2$ and $|f(x)|\leq x(1+e^{-x})$, for $x\in(0,\infty)$. The first property is equivalent to $(f^{3}(x))'\geq 3x^2$, which shows that $f$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$. I tried thinking of a polynomial function, but that was not sufficient. Maybe there is no such function. Any help?

Comment: Correction: $f(x)\geq f(a) + x- a, \forall a\leq x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $g(x)=f(x)^3-x^3$. Observe that $g$ is increasing since $g'(x)=3f(x)^2f'(x)-3x^2\ge 0$, and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 0$ by the given condition $|f(x)|\le x(1+e^{-x})$. Since $g$ is increasing, for each $x$, we have
$$
0\le g(x)\le \lim_{y\to\infty}g(y)= \lim_{y\to\infty}f(y)^3-y^3 \le \lim_{y\to\infty} y^3(3e^{-y}+3e^{-2y}+e^{-3y})=0,
$$ which implies $g(x)=f(x)^3-x^3=0$. Thus we obtain $f(x)=x$.